# Java webservice error - vendor.xml cannot be started

Tags: java, webservice-client

Hi Java web service experts,
I am working on a web service project. My goal is to create a client java program to consume the vendor web service and deliver a data file. I am at the part where I am able to generate the proxy classes from the vendor wsdl document through JDeveloper. Now I start to work to create the java stand alone client application. My issue is I am not able to debug or run my java program because of this following error. I think it has to do with the imported vendor.xml document in Jdeveloper but I am not sure. Below is the error

> The target vendor.xml cannot be started because it is not a runnable
>   target.
>  The target run cannot be started because it does not exist.

I've researched into this issue but not much information came up after all. I am new to this web service and would appreciated all the help.

Comment: how are you loading/accessing the vendor.xml? Also, why are you using the vendor.xml, if you are using the proxy classes?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for responding to my question. To answer the question, the vendor.xml document generated by Jdeveloper together with other skeleton classes. I try to compile or run a very simple java client program that I built just to test out if it compiles or run properly and I get that error. It points to the vendor xml document and says that it cannot run or start because it does not exist.